# How to break the loop from mule 'Splitter' component?

Tags: mule

I know `Splitter` is the asynchronous looping in mule.

I want to break it with some condition. Is there any way to do that ?

OR

It can be done using `For Each` Component ? What component I should drag for breaking the loop ?

I am using `xpath`  to split the xml for looping.

Answer (score 0):

The Splitter creates separate messages for each item in the collection you specify.  If you want to prevent some of those items from being processed, use a [Filter](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Filters) after your Splitter.

Alternately, you can create a more complex xpath to return only the items you want to process.  For example, `/order/item[position() < 4]` would return only the first three item nodes in the document.

If you really want to "break" and ensure that no further items in the collection are processed, you can generate an exception in the body of the [ForEach](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Foreach).  Your flow's exception strategy will be invoked immediately, and no more items will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. A for-each loop that I want to break when a condition is true (the flow is quite more complex, but in a few words...)

I don't think generating a exception is a good idea. The best approach I have reached is for-each and filter expression at the begining of the loop.

Example:

```
 <flow name="break-foreach" processingStrategy="Queued_Asynchronous_Processing_Strategy">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Sat" path="/loop " allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#[[0,1,2,3,4]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <foreach collection="payload" doc:name="For Each">
            <logger message="Iteration before filter: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <expression-filter expression="#[payload&lt;3]" doc:name="Expression"/>
            <logger message="Iteration after filter: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```

The console shows this:

```
Iteration before filter: 0
 Iteration after filter: 0
 Iteration before filter: 1
 Iteration after filter: 1
 Iteration before filter: 2
 Iteration after filter: 2
 Iteration before filter: 3
 Iteration before filter: 4
```

Of course, it is not a break because the for-each keeps processing.